# object pronounce "you" or "yourself" preceding primary object

Tags: pronouns, objects, reflexives

> We would like John and _____ (*you*/*yourself*) to come to the party

Regarding the above sentence, I've done quite a fair bit of Googling and still haven't found a substantial and satisfactory explanation for this. I'm a native speaker of English, yet, I find this question nonetheless perplexing; I can't quite put my finger on it.

---

#### My arguments for  *'you'*

It's an objective pronoun. The example shown below seems grammatically correct and is commonplace in English.

> I would like to see *you* here tomorrow.

#### My arguments for  *'yourself'*

The example shown below seems grammatically accurate as well.

> You love *yourself* more than anyone else.

Comment: Please help us decipher your title.  What does "object pronounce" mean?  How are "you" or "yourself" preceding a "primary object"?

Comment: Consider these related sentences: (*We would like you to come to the party.* (2) *We would like John himself to come to the party.* (3) *We would like you yourself to come to the party.* There's even this: *(4) We would like John himself and you yourself to come to the party.*

Comment: You must mean *pronouns*.

Comment: @HotLicks Sorry, that was a typo of "pronouns".

Comment: @YosefBaskin Yes, I do. My apologies. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, *yourself* is being correctly used as a reflexive form (you love yourself).

If someone invites *you* to a party (with or without another person), the verb is not reflexive, so *yourself* is inappropriate.